# Communication between server to server in twisted

Tags: twisted

This is echoclient code that communicate with echoserver:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()


reactor.listenTCP(8000, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

This is echoserer:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("Hello, world!")
        def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "Server said:", data
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return EchoClient()
    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection failed."
        reactor.stop()
    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
         print "Connection lost."
         reactor.stop()

 reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8000, EchoFactory())
 reactor.run()
```

Above echoserve and echoclient communicate with each other but i want server to server communication, so here other echoserver is came and communicate with first echoserver.

Comment: You can do this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209871/sending-message-from-one-server-to-another-in-twisted/51082096#51082096](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209871/sending-message-from-one-server-to-another-in-twisted/51082096#51082096)

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a proxy client and attach it to one of the servers. And communicate with the other server via the proxy client.